# Locale Spanish in android

Tags: android

I can't find  Locale Spanish in android.
to change the language.

I find:

```
setLocal(Locale.FRENCH);
setLocal(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

but I can find Spanish Locale

```
private void setLocal(Locale locale) {
    Resources res = getResources();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = locale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, res.getDisplayMetrics());
    try {
        Context context = this.createPackageContext(this.getPackageName(),
                Context.CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`public Locale (String language)` will help you.